# Software to find and remove a specific sound (which I have in a separate file) from a multitude of files that have the same sound in different places

Tags: audio, speech-recognition

I need to delete a specific sound (0.4s) from 10,000+ files. The sound is the same in all files, sometimes there are even more than one in the same file. I managed to isolate the noise in a separate file but I do not know how to identify it in the other tracks, even just muting it for that half second would already be more than fine. I saw that there are audio fingerprinting , but can they withstand such a large amount of files or do you have to enter it manually one at a time? The files are all .ogg btw

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As this site is about recommending **software** – can you please **[edit]** your post and add relevant details like what OS must be supported, and what price is acceptable? See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for some guidance. Thanks!